# replace – with - using replace()

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have been using

```
var str = "Artist - Song";
str = str.replace("-", "feat");
```

to change some texts to "-".

Recently, I've noticed another "–" that the above code fails to replace.
This "–" seems a bit longer than the normal "-".

Is there any way to replace the longer one with the shorter "-"?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT.

This is how the rest of the code is written.

```
  var befComma = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('-'));
    befComma.trim();
    var afterhyp = str.substr(str.indexOf("-") + 1);
   var changefeat =  befComma.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 4):

> This "–" seems a bit longer than the normal "-".
>
> Is there any way to replace the longer one with the shorter "-"?

Sure, you just do the same thing:

```
str = str.replace("–", "-");
```

Note that in both cases, you'll only replace the *first* match. If you want to replace all matches, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), which point you at regular expressions with the `g` flag:

```
str = str.replace(/-/g, "feat");
str = str.replace(/–/g, "-");
```

I'm not quite sure why you'd want to replace the longer one with the shorter one, though; don't you want to replace *both* with `feat`?

If so, this replaces the first:

```
str = str.replace(/[-–]/, "feat");
```

And this replaces all:

```
str = str.replace(/[-–]/g, "feat");
```

Comment: I've tried using the above code to replace the longer - with the shorter one. It didn't work out. The reason that I want to replace the longer one is that I have another code running that separates the words at the "-". The code scans for the "-" and then CAPITALIZES the words before the "-". But since the "-" is not getting replaced, the code stops to work. I've edited the question to include this code as well.

Comment: @Chordzone.org: Don't know what to tell you, the above works for the characters you quoted in your question: https://jsfiddle.net/g5rgnLu5/

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
var str = "Artist – Song";
str = str.replace("–", "-"); // Add in this function
str = str.replace("-", "feat");
```

This should replace the slightly longer "–" with the shorter more standard "-".